# wayland - minimal keyboard input example

Tags: c, linux, wayland

I'm adding wayland support to a library. Now I'm adding the input events.

I tried compiling [this example](https://github.com/eyelash/tutorials/blob/master/wayland-input.c), but it crashes with segfault, so I wrote my own version:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wayland-client.h>
#include <xkbcommon/xkbcommon.h>
#include <wayland-egl.h>
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

struct wl_display *display = NULL;
struct wl_seat *seat = NULL;
EGLDisplay egl_display;
struct xkb_context *xkb_context = NULL;
int running = 1;

// seat

void seat_capabilities(void *data, struct wl_seat *seat, uint32_t capabilities) {
    printf("seat_capabilities(%u)\n", capabilities);
    if (capabilities & WL_SEAT_CAPABILITY_KEYBOARD) {
        printf("kb capab\n");
    }
}
struct wl_seat_listener seat_listener = {&seat_capabilities};

// reg

void registry_add_object (void *data, struct wl_registry *registry, uint32_t name, const char *interface, uint32_t version) {
    printf("registry_add_object(%s)\n", interface);
    if (!strcmp(interface, "wl_seat")) {
        printf("  binding seat\n");
        seat = wl_registry_bind(registry, name, &wl_seat_interface, 1);
        wl_seat_add_listener(seat, &seat_listener, NULL);
    }
}
void registry_remove_object (void *data, struct wl_registry *registry, uint32_t name) {
}
struct wl_registry_listener registry_listener = {&registry_add_object, &registry_remove_object};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    display = wl_display_connect(NULL);
    assert(display);
    printf("connected to display\n");

    struct wl_registry *registry = wl_display_get_registry(display);
    assert(registry);
    wl_registry_add_listener(registry, &registry_listener, NULL);
    // Complete init phase
    wl_display_roundtrip(display);

    egl_display = eglGetDisplay(display);
    eglInitialize(egl_display, NULL, NULL);

    xkb_context = xkb_context_new(XKB_CONTEXT_NO_FLAGS);

    //sleep(2);

    eglTerminate(egl_display);
    wl_display_disconnect(display);
    printf("disconnected from display\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

but I don't see anything about keyboard capabilities. Basically the seat listener is never called. Any ideas?

Comment: `<rant>` I don't know how it is now, since I've stop following wayland years ago, a few week after I started. But back then, when I asked about keyboard, the answer of the creator was, in substance "oh... yes... keyboard... there are keyboards too... we'll have to think about that". That the problem when you take 1 minute to decide that X11 is too complicated, and then starts to reinvent the wheel from scratch, instead of developping X12 (and indeed X11 needs heavy repolishing): no multi user, no network (outside of using VNC if you want to), etc. And poor input capabilities `</rant>`

Answer (score 0):

I am not servicing the display enough, and won't get any events on the seat in the first roundtrip.
When I add a second wl_display_roundtrip() the print should fires.
Alternatively, loop on wl_display_dispatch to continously service the connection

```c
    while (running) {
        wl_display_dispatch_pending(display);
    }
```